# How to change Font's ForeColor in ScintillaNet?

Tags: c#, scintillanet

I want to Change Scintilla Net Text Editor's Font Fore color to Black in C#.Net.
i changed like in C# font color.
But it doesn't work.
How can i do that?
Is that change in Styles?
Please Please....answer me..i am having difficult.
Thanks you for your time.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Isn't there anyone to answer my question???

Comment: you posted the question 13 minutes ago - this isn't McDonald's.  It's also the middle of the night in the Western Hemisphere.  Have patience :)

Comment: Can we see the codes you have written for this ...!!

Answer (score 1):

ScintillaNET C# (eg: XML Editor)

```
 scintilla.Lexer = Lexer.Xml;    
 scintilla.Styles[Style.Default].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: This is not a very useful answer. It would make absolutely no sense to someone who had the level of understanding of Scintilla that the asker evidently does. What are styles? What is a lexer? What do these properties do? "I ran this code and I still don't see blue text..." Good answers *explain* what is going on. If the question isn't worth a good answer, then don't bother answering it.

Comment: the person who asked about Scintilla he knows what is  scintilla and lexer and language and styles (CUZ HE IS USING IT)
he asked a Q and I A.
you can comment on me or advice but u can't down vote my answer as long as you didn't provide any answer.

Comment: If he knew all of that and understood how it worked, he wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: no he shouldn't. thats y stackoverflow to help.
he just need help in syntax coding.